# PhoneGap - launch an other app from current app

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

I'm developing a phonegap based app for android and wondering how to run another app or even go to the android marketplace when the wished app is not installed in current device.

Any help  would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this plugin called [WebIntent](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins/). To learn more about intents, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Comment: thanks for the tips, i need to smth different, please look at the update of my question. Any idea?

Comment: @Dozent I would post a new question as I do not have much experience with PhoneGap. You would get much more help this way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Dozent, it is possible but you'll probably end up needing to write a plugin to call an Android Intent. Many of the core PhoneGap API's like Camera use Intents.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android

Comment: so it sounds like there not a native method within Phonegap to handle something like fb:///